# Prove that the bilinear form $a(u,v)=\int_{0}^{1} (-(1+x^2)u'v'-3xu'v) ~\text{d}x$ is coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I want to show that the bilinear form $$a(u,v):=\int_{0}^{1} (-(1+x^2)u'v'-3xu'v) ~\text{d}x$$ is coercive in $H_{0}^1(0,1)$, in order to solve the problem $$(1+x^2)u''-xu'=\sin(2 \pi x)$$ with zero boundary values, so I have:

$$a(u,u)=\int_{0}^{1} (-(1+x^2)(u')^2 -3xu' u )~\text{d}x=\int_{0}^{1} (-(1+x^2)(u')^2+\dfrac{3}{2}u^2)~\text{d}x$$

but I'm stuck in  obtaining $0<\theta$ such that $$\theta |u|_{H_{0}^{1}}^2=\theta \int u^2+(u')^2 ~\text{d}x\leq a(u,u)$$ (coercive), and in fact I believe is not possible, because the leading term is "so negative!". Any suggestion even in the formulation would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the equation is not in divergence form.

Comment: Where does the coefficient $3$ comes from? It is not present in the differential equation.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy It comes from integration by parts and then product rule;
precisely 
$$\int_0^1 -(1+x^2)u''v ~\text{d}x = \int_0^1 (1+x^2)u'v'+2xu'v ~\text{d}x$$ and therefore we get the weak form 
$$\int_0^1 (1+x^2)u'v'+3xu'v ~\text{d}x =-\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x) v ~\text{d}x$$ and now let's define $a(u,v):=\int_0^1 (1+x^2)u'v'+3xu'v ~\text{d}x$.

Comment: Playing around with Hölder and Young I only get something like this (too rigorous I guess)
\begin{align} a(v,v)&=\int_0^1 (1+x^2)|v'|^2 ~dx+\int_0^1 3xv'v ~dx \\ 
& \geq \int_0^1 |v'|^2 ~dx-3\int_0^1 |x| |v| |v'|~dx \\
& \geq ||v'||_{L^2}^2 - 3 ||v||_{L^2} ||v'||_{L^2} \\
& \geq ||v'||_{L^2}^2 \left(1- \frac{3}{2 \epsilon}\right) - \frac{3 \epsilon}{2} ||v||^2_{L^2}  \end{align}
Maybe you could assume coercivity and get it to a contradiction. Or insert your favorite $H_0^1$ function.

Comment: @MarvinF. thanks, got it.